# swift - Generate Code128 from cyrillic string

Tags: ios, swift, cifilter, code128

I need to create a barcode 128 from cyrillic string, so this code, which is working fine for A-Z and numbers, not helps, even if use encoding `let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.windowsCP1251)`

```
func generateBarcode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator") {
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)
        if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {
            return UIImage(ciImage: output)
        } else {
            print("no image!")
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Also I tried RSBarcodes_Swift, but still no result for cyrillic strings. Can please someone help me? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code 128 only supports ASCII (and only a subset of ASCII in any given code set).

You could perform your own mappings to reuse the 128 values as Cyrillic rather than ASCII (i.e. write code to map "A -> A, Б -> B" or something like that), or use Code Set C to encode 2-digit numbers rather than letters, but it'd be up to you to handle encoding and decoding that on both ends. No standard Code 128 system I'm aware of is going to decode it as Cyrillic.

By using [FNC4](https://honeywellaidc.force.com/supportppr/s/article/Code-128-EAN128-Function-Code-4-FNC4), you can encode Latin-1. However, I do not believe this is very commonly implemented, and doesn't help for Cyrillic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Pretty annoying, that it should be readable by any scanner at shop, so custom mapping is not a choice. Android developer of my project realized it with Zxing lib and bitmap rendering, maybe I should try some thing similar

Comment: I'd dig into what they actually built. This isn't an iOS limitation. The format itself doesn't support it. Are you sure that the zxing output is actually Code 128 and not something else?

Comment: and you got the prize! :) just checked their android app and see empty place instead of code128. Should check it first before digging android code. well, we should find another solution for this case. thank you for your time!